# Bootstrap Modal displays while closing the table

Tags: html, html-table, bootstrap-modal

I have table rows under **a** tag and clicking that **a** it expands to show the table, also clicking on same **a** tag it closes the table. For this **a** tag, I have integrated Bootstrap modal i.e when I click on **a** tag it displays modal in front and table in back at the same time. How can I display first modal and after on click submit in modal it should display table. And one more problem is clicking on that same **a** tag to close the table, the modal opens again. Please help me to solve this problems.

Here is the code snippet:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="section">
   <a class="section-title detail-head" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal" href="#accordion-1"> Guidelines and Templates
   </a>
 
 <div id="accordion-1" class="section-content">
    <table class="listingArea">
        <tr style="width:100%;height:50%">
             <td class="col-md-4 col1Listing" id="lnksection1" style="vertical-align:top">

    <table>
        <tr>
             <td class="grouping" id="guidance1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td class="grouping" id="template1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td class="grouping" id="tools1"></td>
        </tr>
   </table>
           
           </td>

       </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i have seen your code, modal code lines are not given by you. As you have mentioned in your question, you can solve your problem by the help of some jquery code. please check the code.

```
<div class="section">

   <a class="section-title detail-head" onclick="modalFunction();"  href="javascript:void(0);"> Guidelines and Templates
   </a>
 <div id="accordion-1" class="section-content" style="display:none;">
    <table class="listingArea">
        <tr style="width:100%;">
             <td class="col-md-4 col1Listing" id="lnksection1" style="vertical-align:top">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                         <td class="grouping" id="guidance1">row 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td class="grouping" id="template1">row 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td class="grouping" id="tools1">row 1</td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
           </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>

<div id="myModal"  class="modal fade agreement_modal" style="display:none">
  <div>
    Modal Section<div>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitModal();">
  </div>
  
</div> 
<script>
function submitModal(){
    $('#accordion-1').show();
    $('#myModal').hide();
}
function modalFunction(){
    $('#accordion-1').hide();
    if($('#myModal').is(':visible')){
        $('#myModal').hide();
        //$('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }else{
        $('#myModal').show();
        //$('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tried your answer and able to get the table things correct but while clicking <a> tag to close table (collapse), the modal still appears. And how can i do this method if there are 7 tables?

Comment: Please update this function of jquery modalFunction()    -                                               function modalFunction(){
 if($('#accordion-1').is(':visible')){
  $('#myModal').hide();
  $('#accordion-1').hide();
 }else{
  $('#accordion-1').hide();
  if($('#myModal').is(':visible')){
   $('#myModal').hide();
   //$('#myModal').modal('hide');
  }else{
   $('#myModal').show();
   //$('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
 }
}